# Combine 40h/week ressources and 80h/week ressources but counting 1day duration as one calendar day both

Tags: ms-project

I want to assess the amount of resources needed to realize a task with calculated work-load and assumed duration. In other words, how many resources do I need to realize workload X in given duration Y.

In the minimum example it's one resource with maximum workload of 100%, but a custom basic calendar that represents a two-shift service, meaning there is a daily capacity of 16h. Resulting in 80h/week:
[image: A]

I tried to start to investigate the difference between the three "freezing" methods: *freezing work*, *freezing duration* or *freezing units* and I thought I understood the connection of those variables.

**1.) Example set up**

The start of the example (before resource allocation step) looks like the following, please compare image B below:

- Each Task (1-3) has a "required" work of 80h
- Each task duration is set to 5 days
- For each task the freezing method is varied

[image: B]

**2.) Resources**

The result of the next step is the allocation of the resource "Maschine" shown in image C below:
[image: C]

**3.) Results vs. Expectations:**

1. I would have expected for Task 2 (with freezing method "fixed duration") that my resource that is able to work 16h per day exactly needs "100%" to realize the given work X=80h
   in given time Y=5days?? Why is MS-project not evenly distributing the work over the five available days and just allocating the work to the first three days?
2. For Task 1 and Task 2, why is MS-Project putting just 1h into the next week, but starts 1h hour later than possible? AND in addition to that, why is then the duration set to 10 days?

Can anybody help me with this problem? Where is my mistake in the settings in order to obtain a for a given task of 80h in a 5 days duration the result off 100% "ressource demand".

Or same example, having X=160h work load in a time of Y=5days resulting in a 200% "ressource demand".

Many thanks!

Comment: David, there is lot more to consider than what you are showing in your screen shots. I suggest you set the option for a date format to include the time (File > Options > General group > Date format). That will likely show why things are starting and finishing later than expected. Also, is the Project calendar set for 16h workdays or is it at the default 8h workday? Is the definition of a day set to 16h or is it at the default 8h? How did you set up the resource's calendar? Take a look at those items and then post back if you still have questions